# Having trouble with MPU6050 and AFE4404 printing together, potential conflict?

Tags: sensors, i2c, mpu6050

I am having trouble getting the two sensors to work together. There are a total of four sensors connected to the Arduino, and while the MPU and AFE individually work fine with the other two sensors, when the two are put together only the Serial Plotter for the AFE shows up while the MPU stays at zero. I initially assumed that there were address conflicts with the two, but their i2c addresses are different: the AFE at 0x58 and the MPU at 0x68 or 0x69. How can I resolve the issue so that I can get all four sensors' graphs printing?
Below is my Arduino code:

```
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include "Wire.h"

//int preValue = 0; 
String str = "0, 0, 0, 0";
int mic = A0;
MPU6050 mpu;
int16_t ax, ay, az;


//PPG Stuff
#define NUM_REGISTERS       40
/* Pinbelegung */

int RESETZ = 4;
int CLK = 5;
int INT = 6;
//const int ocr1aval = 1; //||0 = 8MHz|| 1 = 4MHz|| 3 = 2MHZ ||7 = 1MHz||
const byte interruptPin = 2;

char LED2 = 0x2A; // LED2 on AFE4404

struct Register {
  uint8_t addr;
  uint32_t val;
};
/* Variablendeklaration */

//float befehl = 0;
bool Ready = 1;
int AFE_ADDR = 0x58;

unsigned long counter = 0;

/* AFE440X registers */

#define AFE_CONTROL0                0x00
#define AFE_LED2STC                 0x01
#define AFE_LED2ENDC                0x02
#define AFE_LED1LEDSTC              0x03
#define AFE_LED1LEDENDC             0x04
#define AFE_ALED2STC                0x05
#define AFE_ALED2ENDC               0x06
#define AFE_LED1STC                 0x07
#define AFE_LED1ENDC                0x08
#define AFE_LED2LEDSTC              0x09
#define AFE_LED2LEDENDC             0x0A
#define AFE_ALED1STC                0x0B
#define AFE_ALED1ENDC               0x0C
#define AFE_LED2CONVST              0x0D
#define AFE_LED2CONVEND             0x0E
#define AFE_ALED2CONVST             0x0F
#define AFE_ALED2CONVEND            0x10
#define AFE_LED1CONVST              0x11
#define AFE_LED1CONVEND             0x12
#define AFE_ALED1CONVST             0x13
#define AFE_ALED1CONVEND            0x14
#define AFE_ADCRSTSTCT0             0x15
#define AFE_ADCRSTENDCT0            0x16
#define AFE_ADCRSTSTCT1             0x17
#define AFE_ADCRSTENDCT1            0x18
#define AFE_ADCRSTSTCT2             0x19
#define AFE_ADCRSTENDCT2            0x1A
#define AFE_ADCRSTSTCT3             0x1B
#define AFE_ADCRSTENDCT3            0x1C
#define AFE_PRPCOUNT                0x1D
#define AFE_CONTROL1                0x1E
#define AFE_TIA_GAIN_SEP            0x20
#define AFE_TIA_GAIN                0x21
#define AFE_LEDCNTRL                0x22
#define AFE_CONTROL2                0x23
#define AFE_ALARM                   0x29
#define AFE_LED2VAL                 0x2A
#define AFE_ALED2VAL                0x2B
#define AFE_LED1VAL                 0x2C
#define AFE_ALED1VAL                0x2D
#define AFE_LED2_ALED2VAL           0x2E
#define AFE_LED1_ALED1VAL           0x2F
#define AFE_CONTROL3                0x31
#define AFE_PDNCYCLESTC             0x32
#define AFE_PDNCYCLEENDC            0x33
#define AFE_PROG_TG_STC             0x34
#define AFE_PROG_TG_ENDC            0x35
#define AFE_LED3LEDSTC              0x36
#define AFE_LED3LEDENDC             0x37
#define AFE_CLKDIV_PRF              0x39
#define AFE_OFFDAC                  0x3A
#define AFE_DEC                     0x3D
#define AFE_AVG_LED2_ALED2VAL       0x3F
#define AFE_AVG_LED1_ALED1VAL       0x40



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //ECG
  pinMode(10, INPUT); // Setup for leads off detection LO +
  pinMode(11, INPUT); // Setup for leads off detection LO -

  //PCG
  /*none needed*/

  //PPG
  pinMode(RESETZ, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(INT, INPUT);
  AFE_Init();

  //SCG
  #if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
        Wire.begin();
  #elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
        Fastwire::setup(400, true);
  #endif
  // initialize device
  mpu.initialize();
}

void PCG_Init()
{
  double micOut;
  const int sampleTime = 50;
  double preValue = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  String ECG = "0";
  //String SCG = "0";

  int PCG_val;
  String PCG;
  PCG_val = PCG_loop();
  PCG = String(PCG_val);
  

  int PPG_val;
  String PPG;
  PPG_val = PPG_loop() * -1;
  PPG = String(PPG_val);

//  int ECG_val;
//  String ECG;
//  ECG_val = ECG_loop();
//  ECG = String(ECG_val);

  int SCG_val;
  String SCG;
  SCG_val = SCG_loop();
  SCG = String(SCG_val);

  
  str = PCG + "," + PPG + "," + ECG + "," + SCG;
  Serial.println(str);
  delay(10);
}


//ECG Loop
int ECG_loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if((digitalRead(10) == 1)||(digitalRead(11) == 1)){
  Serial.println('!');
  }
  else{
  // send the value of analog input 0:
  Serial.println(analogRead(A1));
  }
  //Wait for a bit to keep serial data from saturating
  delay(1);
  //delay (30);
}


//SCG Loop
int SCG_loop() {
    mpu.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
    Serial.println(az/(pow(2,9)*1.0));
}

//PCG Loop
int PCG_loop() {
  //switch
  //case 1:
  int returnfill;
   double micOutput = findPTPAmp();
   returnfill = VUMeter(micOutput);   
   return returnfill;
}  

// Find the Peak-to-Peak Amplitude Function
double findPTPAmp(){
// Time variables to find the peak-to-peak amplitude
   unsigned long startTime= millis();  // Start of sample window
   /*unsigned int*/ double PTPAmp = 0; 

// Signal variables to find the peak-to-peak amplitude
   /*unsigned int*/ double maxAmp = 0;
   /*unsigned int*/ double minAmp = 1023;

// Find the max and min of the mic output within the 50 ms timeframe
   while(millis() - startTime < sampleTime) 
   {
      micOut = analogRead(mic);
      if( micOut < 1023) //prevent erroneous readings
      {
        if (micOut > maxAmp)
        {
          maxAmp = micOut; //save only the max reading
        }
        else if (micOut < minAmp)
        {
          minAmp = micOut; //save only the min reading
        }
      }
   }

  PTPAmp = maxAmp - minAmp; // (max amp) - (min amp) = peak-to-peak amplitude
  double micOut_Volts = (PTPAmp * 3.3) / 1024; // Convert ADC into voltage
  return PTPAmp;   
}

// Volume Unit Meter function: map the PTP amplitude to a volume unit between 0 and 10.
int VUMeter(double micAmp){
  double fill = map(micAmp, 23, 750, 0, 10); 
  while(fill != preValue)
  {
    preValue = fill;
  }
  return fill;
}


//PPG Loop
signed long val = 0;
void readADC()
{
  {
    val = AFE_Reg_Read(LED2);
    Ready = 1;
  }
}

int PPG_loop() {
  if (digitalRead(INT))
  {
    val = AFE_Reg_Read(LED2);
  }
  return val;
}




//More PPG Stuff
void AFE_Init()
{
  AFE_RESETZ_Init();
  AFE_Enable_HWPDN();
  AFE_Disable_HWPDN();
  AFE_Trigger_HWReset();
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission (AFE_ADDR);
  Serial.println("Initializing AFE4404...");
  if (Wire.endTransmission () == 0)
  {
    AFE_Enable_Write (); // enable to writting to registers
    AFE_Reg_Init();
    AFE_CLK_Init();
    AFE_Enable_Read ();  // enable to reading from registers
    Serial.println("Initialized Success!");
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Initialized Fail!");

}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                              AFE4404_Registerinitialisierung                                           */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_Reg_Init()
{
  //AFE_Reg_Write(34, 0x0033C3);
  AFEinitRegisters();
}


/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                              AFE4404_Enable_Read                                                       */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_Enable_Read ()         //Prohibit writing to registers
{
  byte configData[3];
  configData[0] = 0x00;
  configData[1] = 0x00;
  configData[2] = 0x01;// 0x01
  I2C_write (AFE_ADDR, AFE_CONTROL0, configData, 3);
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                              AFE4404_Disable_Read                                                      */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_Enable_Write ()        //Permitt writing to registers
{
  byte configData[3];
  configData[0] = 0x00;
  configData[1] = 0x00;
  configData[2] = 0x00; //0x00
  I2C_write (AFE_ADDR, AFE_CONTROL0, configData, 3);
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                  RESETZ des AFE4404 wird Initialisiert                                                 */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_RESETZ_Init()
{
  digitalWrite(RESETZ, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(30);
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                  Reset internal registers by setting RESETZ = LOW for 25 - 50 us                       */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_Trigger_HWReset()
{
  digitalWrite(RESETZ, LOW);              //Sets Arduino pins 22-29 LOW
  delayMicroseconds(30); //30
  digitalWrite(RESETZ, HIGH);              //Sets Arduino pins 22-29 HIGH
  delay(10); // 10
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                             AFE4404 Power Down                                                         */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void  AFE_Enable_HWPDN()
{
  digitalWrite(RESETZ, LOW);                  //Power Down by setting the RESETZ pin to LOW for more than 200 us
  delay(10);
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                AFE4404 Power Up                                                        */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
void  AFE_Disable_HWPDN()
{
  digitalWrite(RESETZ, HIGH);                  //Power Up the AFE by setting the RESETZ pin to HIGH
  delay(10);
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                AFE4404 Set Clock Mode to Internal                                      */
/**********************************************************************************************************/

void AFE_CLK_Init()
{
  AFE_Reg_Write(35, 0x104218);        //Set CLK Mode to internal clock (default Wert: 124218 mit interner CLK)
  AFE_Reg_Write(41, 0x2);             //Don´t set the internal clock to the CLK pin for outside usage
  AFE_Reg_Write(49, 0x000021);        //Division ratio for external clock mode set to fit the Arduino Mega 16MHz
  AFE_Reg_Write(57, 0);               //Set the lowes sampling rate to 61Hz (~17 ms)
}

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                   AFE4404_Reg_Write                                                   */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
void AFE_Reg_Write (int reg_address, unsigned long data)
{
  byte configData[3];
  configData[0] = (byte)(data >> 16);
  configData[1] = (byte)(((data & 0x00FFFF) >> 8));
  configData[2] = (byte)(((data & 0x0000FF)));
  I2C_write(AFE_ADDR, reg_address, configData, 3);
}

/*********************************************************************************************************/
/*                                   AFE4404_Reg_Read                                                    */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
signed long AFE_Reg_Read(int reg_address)
{
  byte configData[3];
  signed long retVal;
  I2C_read (AFE_ADDR, reg_address, configData, 3);
  retVal = configData[0];
  retVal = (retVal << 8) | configData[1];
  retVal = (retVal << 8) | configData[2];
  if (reg_address >= 0x2A && reg_address <= 0x2F)
  {
    if (retVal & 0x00200000)  // check if the ADC value is positive or negative
    {
      retVal &= 0x003FFFFF;   // convert it to a 22 bit value
      return (retVal ^ 0xFFC00000);
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                              Write to AFE on I2C                                                       */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
char I2C_write (int slave_address, int reg_address, byte configData[], int byteCount)
{
  int trans_end = 0;
  signed long retVal;

  Wire.beginTransmission(slave_address);
  Wire.write(reg_address);
  Serial.print(configData[0]);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(configData[1]);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(configData[2]);
  retVal = configData[0];
  retVal = (retVal << 8) | configData[1];
  retVal = (retVal << 8) | configData[2];
  Serial.println(retVal);
  Serial.println(reg_address);
  Wire.write(configData, 3);
  Serial.println("test");
  Wire.endTransmission();
  return (trans_end);

  /* while(1)
    {
     if(byteCount == 0)
     {
       Wire.endTransmission();
       Serial.println("test");
       return (trans_end);
     }else{
       //unsigned int reg_data = (unsigned int) *write_data++;
       Wire.write(configData, 3);
       byteCount--;
     }
    }*/
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
/*                              Read Data of AFE on I2C                                                   */
/**********************************************************************************************************/
char I2C_read(int slave_address, int reg_address, byte *read_Data, int byteCount)
{
  int trans_end = 0;

  Wire.beginTransmission(slave_address);
  Wire.write(reg_address);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(slave_address, 3);
  while (Wire.available() && (byteCount != 0))
  {
    *read_Data++ = Wire.read();
    byteCount--;
  }
  return (trans_end);
}

void AFEinitRegisters(void) {

  unsigned char i;
  struct Register reg[NUM_REGISTERS];
  reg[0].addr = 0x01; reg[0].val = 0x000050;
  reg[1].addr = 0x02; reg[1].val = 0x00018F;
  reg[2].addr = 0x03; reg[2].val = 0x000320;
  reg[3].addr = 0x04; reg[3].val = 0x0004AF;
  reg[4].addr = 0x05; reg[4].val = 0x0001E0;
  reg[5].addr = 0x06; reg[5].val = 0x00031F;
  reg[6].addr = 0x07; reg[6].val = 0x000370;
  reg[7].addr = 0x08; reg[7].val = 0x0004AF;
  reg[8].addr = 0x09; reg[8].val = 0x000000;
  reg[9].addr = 0x0A; reg[9].val = 0x00018F;
  reg[10].addr = 0x0B; reg[10].val = 0x0004FF;
  reg[11].addr = 0x0C; reg[11].val = 0x00063E;
  reg[12].addr = 0x0D; reg[12].val = 0x000198;
  reg[13].addr = 0x0E; reg[13].val = 0x0005BB;
  reg[14].addr = 0x0F; reg[14].val = 0x0005C4;
  reg[15].addr = 0x10; reg[15].val = 0x0009E7;
  reg[16].addr = 0x11; reg[16].val = 0x0009F0;
  reg[17].addr = 0x12; reg[17].val = 0x000E13;
  reg[18].addr = 0x13; reg[18].val = 0x000E1C;
  reg[19].addr = 0x14; reg[19].val = 0x00123F;
  reg[20].addr = 0x15; reg[20].val = 0x000191;
  reg[21].addr = 0x16; reg[21].val = 0x000197;
  reg[22].addr = 0x17; reg[22].val = 0x0005BD;
  reg[23].addr = 0x18; reg[23].val = 0x0005C3;
  reg[24].addr = 0x19; reg[24].val = 0x0009E9;
  reg[25].addr = 0x1A; reg[25].val = 0x0009EF;
  reg[26].addr = 0x1B; reg[26].val = 0x000E15;
  reg[27].addr = 0x1C; reg[27].val = 0x000E1B;
  reg[28].addr = 0x1D; reg[28].val = 0x009C3F;
  reg[29].addr = 0x1E; reg[29].val = 0x000103;
  reg[30].addr = 0x20; reg[30].val = 0x008025; //0x008003
  reg[31].addr = 0x21; reg[31].val = 0x000125;//0x000003 //bit8: PROG_TG_EN
  reg[32].addr = 0x22; reg[32].val = 0x000100;//ILED2 = 32
  reg[33].addr = 0x23; reg[33].val = 0x000000;
  reg[34].addr = 0x32; reg[34].val = 0x00155F;
  reg[35].addr = 0x33; reg[35].val = 0x00991F;
  reg[36].addr = 0x36; reg[36].val = 0x000190;
  reg[37].addr = 0x37; reg[37].val = 0x00031F;
  reg[38].addr = 0x34; reg[38].val = 0x001563;
  reg[39].addr = 0x35; reg[39].val = 0x00991F;

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_REGISTERS; i++)
    AFE_Reg_Write(reg[i].addr, reg[i].val);

}
```

I am plotting each of the four sensors on LabView. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You never change ECG to anything from 0, so of course it's always zero.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with this program. It's such a mess I don't think it's salvageable. You should learn some basic C syntax before you start programming.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting I2C issues can be frustrating.  In order to figure out the problem, I recommend you construct the simplest possible Arduino sketch, using just the two sensors that seem to have a problem working together.  You should be able to write a very simple program that does nothing but acquire a simple value from each sensor, say 2 times/second.

Once you have the simplest possible program running, you should be able to figure it out.  Right now all your program complexity is making it harder than it needs to be.

Good luck!

Frank